# Python collecting outputs into a list?

Tags: python, list, collatz

Instead of printing the numbers in the sequence it should collect them in a list and return the list.
Here is the code that prints numbers in the sequence:

```
def collatz_sequence(n):
    while n > 1:
        print(n)
        if n % 2 == 1:
            n = 3*n + 1
        else:
            n = n // 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
def collatz_sequence(n):
    lst = []
    while n > 1:
        lst.append(n)
        if n % 2 == 1:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        else:
            n = n // 2
    return lst
```

---

Here is a note:

Since `n` is an integer, `n % 2` can only equal to `1` or `0`, hence

```
if n % 2 == 1:
```

can be simplified to

```
if n % 2:
```